# Can I print out a preprocessor value in a message/warning in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, c-preprocessor

I want to print out (during compilation) messages telling me about some preprocessor settings in an Xcode5 C++ project. I believe there is no standard way of doing this (I've done it using  tricks in VC++ before).

How can I make this code print out the actual value of `__ENVIRONMENT_IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__`?

```
#   if __ENVIRONMENT_IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__ >= 60000 || __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 60000
#       define OGRE_PLATFORM OGRE_PLATFORM_APPLE_IOS
#   else
#       define OGRE_PLATFORM OGRE_PLATFORM_APPLE
#   endif
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
#define STR(X) #X
#define DEFER(M,...) M(__VA_ARGS__)
#pragma message "min version required is " DEFER(STR,__ENVIRONMENT_IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__)
```

Hat tip (and reference link) to the [Clang User Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas).